# Ant+ hardware support broken in Android 9?

Tags: updates, 8.0-oreo, xiaomi, 9.0-pie, ant-plus

Recently, my Xiaomi Mi A1 received an update to Android 9, and since that I figured out that Ant+ is not working anymore (which did work pefectly using Android 8).

Ant Radio tester from the Google playstore says that no built-in ANT was found, the services are all installed correctly however.

First I thought this is a problem only related to this Xiaomi model, but in the meantime I am convinced this must be something related to Android 9, since also users of other brands (including Nokia and other Xiaomi phones) report the same after updating their phones to Android 9.

So the questions simply are:

1.) did Google break Ant+ support in Android 9?

2.) How can this be fixed?

Comment: 1) I believe this is the case based on two other devices, a OnePlus 3 that worked before an update to android 9 pie and didn't work afterwards and a Moto g7 power, which came with pie and doesn't work. I've not found any official confirmation or solution yet.